# Requesting SoftLayer VM with Python API Unable to Find Price for Block Device 3

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to request a SoftLayer VM with the Python API, but I am getting an error when the vsi includes 3 disks.

Error:

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound): Unable to find a price for block device 3.
```

Here is the vsi:

```
new_vsi = {
        'domain': domain,
        'hostname': hostname + str(n),
        'datacenter': datacenter,
        'dedicated': False,
        'private': False,
        'cpus': number_of_cpus,
        'os_code' : u'UBUNTU_LATEST_64', 
        'hourly': is_hourly_billed,
        'disks': ['100','200', '100'],
        'local_disk': True,
        'memory': 16384,
        'private_vlan': privatevlan,
        'public_vlan': publicvlan,
        'nic_speed':1000
}
```

If I only have two disks in the list there won't be any errors, but if I add a third disk to the list I will get the above error. I have tried various values for the third disk, including: 25, 100, 150, 200, and 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your configuration `'local_disk': True,` the device 3 (or disk 3) only is available for dedicated hosts or non-local disk, if you change it to `'local_disk': False`, it should work.

Comment: Is there any way to have the VM request contain 3 disks with the first 2 being local and then the third being a SAN? I know you can request the third disk after the VM has been requested with placeOrder(order), but I would prefer it if I can get the third disk along with the VM request rather than afterwards.

Comment: Yep it is possible you need to use the placeOrder  method to order the VM  instead the current one you are using

Comment: and what about the size? I'm trying some bigger disks but the value does not seems to be recognized.... trying a single 500GB disk for instance also fails

Comment: you need to use getcreateObjectOptions method to get all available sizes for the disk see https://softlayer.github.io/article/vsiflavors/ if the disk size is not list you will not be able to created, but if the size is available it probably is an issue